# Green's function of screened Coulomb interaction using partial Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, integration, greens-functions

The solution of the differential equation (DGL)
$$
(-\epsilon_0\nabla^2  + l^{-2} )G(\vec{r},\vec{r}') = \delta(\vec{r},\vec{r}')
$$
is given by a screened Coulomb potential
$$
G(\vec{r},\vec{r}') = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{e^{-\vert\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\vert/l}}{\vert\vec{r}-\vec{r}'}, 
$$
with $l$ being some screening length. I would say that this can be shown most straightforward in spherical coordinates with an inverse fouriertransform (FT) in conjunction with a contour integral.

I would like to show this using a partial FT in $(x,y)$ direction. Note that I omit the vector arrows from now on. The partial FT in $(x,y)$ coordinates to $(\rho,\phi)$ yields
$$
\delta(r-r')=\frac{1}{4\pi^{2}}\int d^{2}k\;\delta(z-z')\;e^{i\boldsymbol{k}\cdot\boldsymbol{\rho}} \\
=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int dk\;\delta(z-z')\;k\cdot J_{0}(k\cdot\rho),
$$
and
$$
G(r,r')=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\phi\cdot k\;g(k,z,z')\;e^{ik\rho\cos(\phi)}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\;k\;g(k,z,z')\;J_{0}(k\cdot\rho).
$$
These two equations inserted into the DGL above yields
$$
\left(-\partial_{z'}^{2}+k^{2}+l^{-2}\right)g(k,z,z') = \frac{1}{2\pi\epsilon_0}\delta(z-z'),
$$
whose solution is given by
$$
g(k,z,z')=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+l^{-2}}}e^{-\sqrt{k^2+l^{-2}}\vert z'-z\vert}.
$$
Then the Green's function should be given by the inverse FT
$$
G(r,r')=\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\;k\;g(k,z,z')\;J_{0}(k\cdot\rho)
=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_{0}^{\infty}dk\;J_{0}(k\cdot\rho)\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^2+l^{-2}}}e^{-\sqrt{k^2+l^{-2}}\vert z'-z\vert}.
$$
Unfortunately, I can't find much literature on how to evaluate these types of integrals involving the Bessel function. Therefore, I would appreciate some ideas on how to solve this $k$ integration.